# Where is the best place to check for referential integrity in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best practice and/or best place to check that a model's relationship id (ie. foreign key) is valid in Rails?

1) The model validation:

```
class User
  validate :child_exists

  def child_exists
   errors.add(:child, "doesn't exist") if Child.where(id: self.child_id).nil?
  end
end
```

2) Just the database

```
  add_foreign_key :users, :children
```

I know this is the only way to guarantee referential integrity, but this will cause an exception when trying to save, rather than a normal non-success that can be used in `if @user.save`.

3) Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If referential integrity is a major concern in your application then adding the foreign key constraint is the best way to go. Yes you won't be able to do `if @user.save` however you can simply rescue the exception and handle it according to your needs. Hope this helps.